# Record Selection formula in Crystal filtering too much

Tags: filter, crystal-reports-2008

I'm trying to show records that have a certain DocumentName, where the id numbers don't match, but also show ones where the id number is blank, but every time I add the part about not matching id's with that document name, the blank ones drop out.  I'm using "or", so why is it removing them?  How do I fix it?  My parenthesis look ok to me. This is what I have in Report->SelectionFormulaEditor:

```
//first part that makes second part lose the blanks
(not({Person.ID_Number}={Person_ID_Numbers.ID_Number})
and
{Person_ID_Numbers.DocumentName}="Verification")
or

//second part that works fine without first part
isnull({Person.ID_Number})
or({Person.ID_Number}="")
or(CStr({Person.ID_Number})="")
or
isnull({Person_ID_Numbers.ID_Number})
or({Person_ID_Numbers.ID_Number}="")
or(CStr({Person_ID_Numbers.ID_Number})="")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  There was was a menu in Selection Formula Editor and it had "Exceptions for Nulls"

[image: ExceptionNulls]

selected.  I selected "Default Value for Nulls" and the nulls/blanks showed up.